# accessing maps interface value in Go

Tags: go

I am using Maps in Go like
Map[Key]interface{}

so my key-value pair inside Map looks like -

```
map[
 1:{12234 145 1000} 
    1234:{1234 15 1000} 
    12:{12 12345 1000}]
```

where **1 is the key** and {12234,145,1000} is the value corresponds to that key

And this is struct which is a image of value inside the map

```
 type AddStruct struct {
    AdID         int
    Category     int
    Impression   int
 }

    type Handler struct {
    Conmap cmap.ConcurrentMap 
   }
```

I am using concurrent maps in Go This is how i am adding key-value pair to maps

```
   func  (h *Handler) Add(input AddStruct){
       AdID := strconv.Itoa(input.AdID)
       h.Conmap.Set(AdID,input)
    }
```

But the problem that I am facing in accessing them is 
I need to return all the key value pairs from the map which are having same category specified in function argument

```
func(h *Handler) Fetch(category int) []int {
    h.Conmap.IterCb(func(key string, v interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", key) //1
    fmt.Printf("%v\n",v.(AddStruct)) // {12234 145 1000}

     I only need 145 to here to check! Or how do i access 145 here ?


})
}
```

**So how do i access each value inside the value interface??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
v.(AddStruct).Category
```

After a valid type assertion, you can access struct fields with a valid selector for the asserted type.  See, e.g., this runnable example:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

type AddStruct struct {
    AdID         int
    Category     int
    Impression   int
}

func main() {
    a := AddStruct{12234, 145, 1000}
    var b interface{}
    b = a
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", b.(AddStruct).Category)
}
```

prints `145`